# How to remove baseline from google column chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have created the column chart with Google map. Have to remove baseline... attached the image file.

[image: in that image have to remove baseline and add values on bar as per colors]

I tried, but didnt get it. any idea appreciated.

Comment: I have already set like this..... hAxis: { gridlines: { count: 0, color: 'transparent' }, textPosition: 'none', baselineColor: 'transparent' }

Comment: set like this...working fine... thank you..                                          baselineColor: 'transparent',
vAxis: { gridlines: { count: 0, color: 'transparent' }, },
 hAxis: { textPosition: 'none'},

Comment: Add your comment as answer and accept it @VJS, it really helped me and will help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `baselineColor` in the vAxis options

```
        vAxes: {
            0: {
                (...)
                gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},
                baselineColor: 'transparent',
                (...)
            },
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `baseline` in the vAxis options

```
        vAxes: {
            0: {
                (...)
                gridlines: {color: 'transparent'},
                baseline: 'none',
                (...)
            },
        },
```